# imagepicker jQuery callback clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using this http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ library
and I don't know how to show the value of the src image when clicked.

Can you help me?

This is my example:

```
$("select.image-picker.show-labels").imagepicker({
  hide_select:  true, 
  show_label:   true,
  clicked:function(){
      console.log($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
  }
});
```

Comment: the value is undefined, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it :

`$(this).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").data('img-src');`

`$(this)` is the select input, you're trying to find the option which is selected and to get the img-src data attribute.

Though, are you sure you shouldn't just get the Id of the image you selected through `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: $(this).val() return for console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: Make jsfiddle then or it'll be tough to go any further.

Comment: Alright i've checked a few things and the problem (IMHO) comes from the image-picker plugin which doesn't gives back this variable. I corrected it and sent a pull request on github, also i forked the repository to be able to use it on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FCg5L/1/

Comment: How good you are, and work
You're a machine.
Thank you so much.
A big hug Florian

Comment: according to this thread https://github.com/rvera/image-picker/issues/35
you need to use   this.val()